# (Co)limits of adic spaces

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry

Which (co)limits exist in the category of adic spaces ? Also, can we impose adjectives such as "noetherian" or "quasi-compact", etc., to get more (co)limits ? I know that finite fibre products of *affinoids* exist within the category, but I have not been able to find references indicating that other (co)limits also exist, and I am not yet familiar enough with adic spaces to be able to test out a few examples on my own to see if other (co)limits should exist.

Comment: [_The Monsky-Washnitzer and the overconvergent realizations_](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01718) by Vezzani mentions in Appendix A that inverse limits in the category of adic spaces don't exist, but also that there's a notion of "being similar to an inverse limit".

Comment: @Emily What about (countable) filtered colimits ? I've seen a few, particularly the adic affine line, which is isomorphic to the "union" of adic closed discs with increasing radii, but I can not tell if say, only colimits of a filtered diagram of closed immersions would remain inside the category of adic spaces, or if there are more general colimits (incidentally, this also raises the question of how closed immersions should be defined categorically).

Comment: @Day Minh Ha Sorry, I don't know :/ (I've just started to learn about adic spaces, and am currently quite unfamiliar with most of the material...)

Comment: I've found however something possibly useful: there are some references mentioning that the situation for fibre products is actually quite delicate. Firstly, there's this basic positive result for finite type morphisms: Huber's _Étale Cohomology of Rigid Analytic Varieties and Adic Spaces_ states in Prop. 1.2.2 that the fibre product of two morphisms of adic spaces $f\colon X\to Z$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ in the category of adic spaces exists if 1) $f$ is locally of finite type or 2) $f$ is locally of weakly finite type and $g$ is adic.

Comment: However, [Alex Youcis's PhD thesis](https://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/etd/ucb/text/Youcis_berkeley_0028E_18804.pdf) states in p.93: "_[...] we would now like to recall the definition of the fiber product of adic spaces. Of course, this is not so simple of an affair in general. And, in fact, the fiber product of arbitrary adic spaces (even affinoid adic spaces!) doesn't exist._".

Comment: Then, Kedlaya–Liu's [_Relative p-adic Hodge theory: Foundations_](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.0792) reads in Remark 8.2.5: _The categories of locally v-ringed spaces and preadic spaces admit fibred products. However, it is unknown whether the fibred product of adic spaces (over an adic space) is again an adic space. A counterexample would necessarily involve nonnoetherian Banach rings thanks to Proposition 2.4.16; on the other hand, the example of perfectoid spaces (§8.3) shows that failure of the noetherian property alone is not sufficient._

Comment: @Emily Yes my assertion that general finite pullbacks exist in the category of adic spaces was a mistake :p Finite pullbacks of *affinoids*, however, do exist (in particular, one has $\mathbf{Spa}(B, B^+) \times_{\mathbf{Spa}(A, A^+)} \mathbf{Spa}(C, C^+) \cong \mathbf{Spa}\left(B \otimes_A C, B^+ \otimes_{A^+} C^+\right)^{\wedge}$, and there is also a terminal object, namely $\mathbf{Spa}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$, and so finite products of affinoids also exist ...

Comment: @Emily ... The issue with non-affinoid adic spaces, I believe, is that one needs to make sure the ideals of definition of the affinoid patches do not get mapped to something "infinite" by out (co)limits.

Comment: Oh, nice! For the formula for fibre products of affinoids as a tensor product, do we need finiteness assumptions for the morphisms $\mathrm{Spa}(B,B^+),\mathrm{Spa}(C,C^+)\to\mathrm{Spa}(A,A+)$? I've seen the result stated with these hypotheses before, so I'm not completely sure... (By the way, I just noticed I mistyped a 'y' instead of a 't' in your name in one of my comments above; sorry! :/)

Comment: (By the way, this is a somewhat off-topic remark/question, but given that Huber pairs embed fully faithfully in Clausen–Scholze's category of analytic rings, I wonder if one can 'solve' the issue of having many non-existing co/limits of adic spaces by passing to their framework and considering instead co/limits of analytic spaces―do all of these exist?)

Comment: @Emily I could be mistaken, but I do not believe you need any finiteness assumption when taking finite (fibred) products of affinoids. The ideals of definition shouldn't "amalgamate" into something infinite, and in terms of examples, we know that the pullback of two perfectoid affinoids is again a perfectoid affinoids, and perfectoid algebras are almost never "finite" in any way (finite type, Noetherian, etc.).

Comment: @Emily As of right now I don't know much condensed mathematics. Perhaps what you're hinting towards will be for another MO thread.

Comment: Thanks! I shared your question on these two AG discord servers: [1](https://discord.gg/69dXCSY9), [2](https://discord.gg/UqdsuYdR), and in the first one algebraiccyclist said the following:

Comment: "The claimed fiber product of affinoid adic spaces is incorrect; in general it need not be affinoid (and it is not clear to me whether it exists in general).  For example, consider the fiber product $$\mathrm{Spa}(\mathbb{Q}_p,\mathbb{Z}_p)\times_{\mathrm{Spa}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}_p)}\mathrm{Spa}(\mathbb{Z}_p[[u]], \mathbb{Z}_p[[u]])$$ --- this fiber product exists and it is the open unit rigid analytic disk, which is not quasi-compact, let alone affinoid"

Comment: "see example 5.5 here for more detail on this example: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/Perfseminar/Notes/L5.pdf"

Comment: (P.S. The condensed question is definitely off-topic here (and maybe might be a nice one for another question on MO, though I figure it would be better to wait for Clausen–Scholze to release the longer version of their manuscript first). I just thought it might be something nice to mention since it's certainly unsatisfying that so many co/limits of adic spaces don't exist, and possible fixes to these problems are always nice =)

Comment: @Emily I forgot to specify that I was taking pullbacks along adic morphisms (I'm just concerned with adic morphisms in my notes at the moment, and I forgot to switch back to the general case). If the morphisms are not adic (i.e. if there lacks a compatibility of topology) then I believe that pullbacks of affinoids should remain an affinoid. In general, as your example demonstrates, this is not the case (particularly, $p\mathbb{Z}_p[\![u]\!]$ is not the ideal of definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\![u]\!]$).

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks, Dat! (By the way, the example is not mine, it's algebraiccyclist's who posted it in the number theory Discord)