# References on topological ringed spaces

Tags: valuation-theory, valuation-rings, locally-ringed-spaces, ringed-spaces, topological-rings

This is a follow up to [this question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/q/402931/143390).

First of all, let me fix some terminologies, which may or may not be standard:

> Definition: A **topological ringed space** is a pair $X := (|X|, \mathcal{O}_X)$ where $|X|$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a sheaf of (commutative) topological rings. Such a space is said to be a **topological locally ringed space** if the stalks of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ are all local rings.

My questions are then:

1. Are there issues with these definitions of mine ?
2. Is there a decently extensive reference on these kinds of topological ringed spaces ? The only thing I have managed to find is [this tiny nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topologically+ringed+space#:%7E:text=A%20topologically%20ringed%20space%20is,case%20of%20the%20ringed%20spaces.).

Thank you!

Comment: Your definition is exactly the same as the one in The Stacks Project and in EGA! The former has a small bit of material on locally topologically ringed spaces (LTRSs) in [Tag 0AHY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AHY), while the later defines those in [EGA 0, Section 4](https://labs.thosgood.com/ega/ega0-auto.pdf) and talks a bit more about them in the section on formal schemes ([EGA 1, Section 10](https://labs.thosgood.com/ega/ega1-auto.pdf)). Both the Stacks Project and EGA pass very quickly to formal schemes, though, and I also don't know of an extensive general reference for LTRSs :/